Avoid having to re-build projects while using .NET Aspire
I started using .NET Aspire to make development and troubleshooting of a few closely related microservices easier. Overall this works great but 1 downside is that I am having to build each microservice every time I want to try out a new change.
builder.AddProject("Service1", "{project path")
    .WithDaprSidecar("service-1");
builder.AddProject("Service2", "{project path}")
    .WithDaprSidecar("service2");

Each microservice in my company is in a separate repo so I am having to reference projects by a relative file path. I'm not sure if that is part of the problem but it is not an option to have all microservices in 1 .net solution.
Additionally, I am using Dapr. I don't think this necessarily changes thing but the application are certainly started in a different way so mentioning it just in case.
Is there a way to get .NET Aspire to build projects before starting them so me and my team members don't have to remember to do it every time?

I stumbled upon this plugin for Rider that seems to do everything I needed - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/23289--net-aspire.
Looks like Aspire doesn't focus on building your code and leaves that to the IDE, which is fair enough.
